# Complexity Recursion in For

Tags: recursion, time, time-complexity

Hi i wanted to know how can i solve the tine complexity of this algorithm

I solved with f(n/4) but not f(n/i)

```py
void f(int n){

   if (n<4) return;

   for (int i=0;i*i<n;i++)
    printf("-");

   for (int i=2;i<4;i++)
     f(n/i);              // solved the case f(n/4) but stuck f(n/i)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the loop condition is `i<4`, so `i` never reaches 4. i.e. the only recursive terms are `f(n/2)` and `f(n/3)`.

Recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + Θ(sqrt(n))
```

There are two ways to approach this problem:

1. Find upper and lower bounds by replacing one of the recursive terms with the other:

   ```
   R(n) = 2T(n/3) + Θ(sqrt(n))
   S(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(sqrt(n))

   R(n) ≤ T(n) ≤ S(n)
   ```

   You can easily solve for both bounds by substitution or applying the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)):

   ```
   R(n) = O(n^[log3(2)]) = O(n^0.63...)
   S(n) = O(n)
   ```
2. If you need an *exact* answer, use the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method):

   ```
   a1 = a2 = 1
   h1(x) = h2(x) = 0
   g(x) = sqrt(x)
   b1 = 1/2
   b2 = 1/3
   ```

   You need to solve for a power `p` such that `[1/2]^p + [1/3]^p = 1`. Do this numerically with e.g. Newton-Raphson, to obtain `p = 0.78788...`. Perform the integral:

   [image: [1]]

   ‒ to obtain `T(n) = O(n^0.78...)`, which is consistent with the bounds found before.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is about **O(sqrt(9/2) * sqrt(n))** time, but I'd go with **O(sqrt(n))** to be safe. It's admittedly been a while since I worked with time complexity.

If n < 4, the function returns immediately, at constant time `O(1)`

If n >= 4, the function's for loop, `for (int i=0; i*i<n; i++)` performs the constant-time function `printf("-");` a total number of `sqrt(n)` times. So far we're at `O(sqrt(n))` time.

The next for loop performs two recursive calls: one for `f(n/2)` and one for `f(n/3)`

- The first runs in `O(sqrt(n/2))` time, the second in `O(sqrt(n/4))` time, and so on - this series converges to `O(sqrt(2n))`
- Likewise, the function `f(n/3)` converges to `O(sqrt(3/2 n))`

**This doesn't factor in** the fact that each recursive call also invokes a little extra time by calling both of these functions when it runs, but I *believe* this converges to about `O(sqrt(n)) + O(sqrt(2n)) + O(sqrt(3/2 n))`, which itself converges to `O(sqrt(9/2) * sqrt(n))`

This is likely a little low bit low for an *exact* constant value, but I believe you can safely say this runs at **O(sqrt(n)) time**, with some small-ish constant out front.

Comment: Big-O refresher 101: external multiplicative factors are irrelevant.

Comment: It hurts to see how rusty I've become, I can't believe I forgot that. That being said, after a little research, I was considering leaving it in. If I understood this right, multiplicative factors are irrelevant for problems of arbitrary size, but can be important when `n` is small.

Comment: Big-O refresher 102: in the context of algorithms, asymptotic notation (and indeed asymptotic analysis) is only relevant for **large** inputs :)